# Angular2: Unterminated string constant

Tags: html, angular, angular-components

I'm having trouble while i'm creating an html file for my component. The weird fact about this is because this error is not being shown on the other components...

Looks like it's an encoding problem, but i've changed the encoding of the html code, but it's not working neither.

Here's my html:

```html
 <div class="login">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="form access">
     <div class="header-form">
      <h1>Criar nova senha</h1>
      <p>Oi Bruno, digita a senha que você vai      querer usar para o seu SebraeID.</p>
     </div>
     <form id="form-new-password">
      <div class="form-control">
       <label for="">Nova senha</label>
       <input type="text" name="new-password" placeholder="Nova senha" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
       <label for="">Confirmar nova senha</label>
       <input type="text" name="confirm-password" placeholder="Nova senha" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-control recaptcha">
     
      </div>
      <div class="form-control button">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Definir</button>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

And here's the terminal's response:

[image]

Comment: you seems to be using quotation marks instead of backtick which might be causing that error

Comment: Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (` `) ,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: OP says they are "creating an html file", which can also be seen in the console error: `edit-password.component.html`. It is not an inline template. @jjoaovictortinoco can you please show the `@Component` decorator of your component?

Answer (score 2):

It is an encoding problem. I found it by copying your HTML code in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2yfgbw?file=app%2Fapp.component.html). You have some strange, invisible character on line 6 between "você vai " and the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, use back-tick() instead of quotation marks

```
template:`<div class="login">
       <div class="container">
          <div class="form access">
              <div class="header-form">
                  <h1>Criar nova senha</h1>
                  <p>Oi Bruno, digita a senha que você vai          querer usar para o seu SebraeID.</p>
              </div>
              <form id="form-new-password">
                  <div class="form-control">
                      <label for="">Nova senha</label>
                      <input type="text" name="new-password" placeholder="Nova senha" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-control">
                      <label for="">Confirmar nova senha</label>
                      <input type="text" name="confirm-password" placeholder="Nova senha" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-control recaptcha">

                  </div>
                  <div class="form-control button">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Definir</button>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>`
```

Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick () , check this link for more details developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/…

Comment: His template is in an html file, as indicated in his error message.

Comment: Yep, it's working now. However, i didn't understand why it's not working on my html file. Probably some encoding issues like the mentioned above. Thanks anyway!